# make web2py application available on the web

Tags: python, web2py

I have create a simple and small web2py application that i want to make public to the world.

I am new to web development and need some help and guidance.

Thanks in Advance.

Cheers

Comment: Did you read the [deployment recipes](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13) from the manual?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you have a hosting provider? Are you trying to set up a web server? What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get started is to register on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ (which is free for basic usage). They offer a pre-configured setup for web2py so you won't have any trouble setting up the server.

Once you have web2py running you can use the usual web2py admin interface to upload your packaged web2py app. If you have never heard about this before, take a look at this: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03#More-on-admin